# compiling python code from gedit

Tags: python, gedit

I am using WinXP.
I am using gedit (2.30.1) as python IDE. But I don't how to compile my code from inside the gedit. I've searched the net, but can't found any good solution.

Comment: You want to compile it into what? `.pyc`? `.exe`?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you don't compile a python code. Python's code is interpreted.

**EDIT:**

gedit doesn't come by default with the plugins necessary to do the development. You will have to install them. Look in the comment for the link.

You can also checkout a [blog link.](http://trialsolution.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/gedit-as-a-python-ide/)

Comment: You could also use the IDLE tool, which ships with python.

Comment: -1 for saying that he needs Eclipse and that gedit is not an IDE. Gedit is very extensible, it allows you to add plugins like these for Python console, Django development, Python profiling and so on... See http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins (from the site: "_Add Python debugging capabilities to make gedit a nice Python IDE._", "_(...) make gedit a lightweight IDE_").

Answer (score 0):

Using *any* simple text editor won't give you much flexibility in running the code right from the application.  Unless you add a few plugins here and there to gEdit, you couldn't do it natively from Linux either.

If you're keen on sticking with gEdit for your needs, then you would have to install the plugins in your system - [here is a link](http://salehenrahman.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/installing-gedit-plugins-in-windows-7-vista-and-maybe-xp/) that may be of use to you.  If you're fine with moving to another text editor, then I would strongly recommend Geany, which does the same thing as gEdit, but is more fully-featured, and can allow for execution of code in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never need to compile Python code, although sometimes, as a optimization, Python code could be transfered into C code for a higher performance with certain plugins. Python code are translated to *.pyc and run in a PVM.